# window.innerWidth in Chrome's device mode

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, viewport

When in google chrome's device mode, what does window.innerWidth return? Is it the viewport of the device (plus any scroll bars)?

I'm getting different values for the device's width x height (the dimensions on top of the page - the device's viewport?) and window.innerWidth x window.innerHeight (browser's viewport?). Is this supposed to happen?

Here's a picture of what I'm getting, and the code I used.

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
var image;

window.onload = function() {
  image = document.getElementById("img");
  checkWindowSize();
  window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    checkWindowSize();
  });
}

function checkWindowSize() {
  var width = window.innerWidth,
      height = window.innerHeight;

  console.log("window.innerHeight: ", window.innerHeight, " window.innerWidth: ", window.innerWidth);
}
</script>

<img id="img" class="vid-img-filter" src="http://i.imgur.com/jkhFJMn.jpg" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`window.innerWidth` and `innerHeight` return the dimensions of the visual viewport. In desktop browsers, this is generally the browser's window dimensions. On mobile the situation is a bit more complicated because of pinch zoom.

When you load a page without a `<meta name="viewport">` tag, a default layout width is used (e.g. Chrome uses 980px). When the browser loads the page it does so maximally zoomed out. It looks like your device size above has a width of 425px so the browser zooms out when the page is loaded to see the whole 980px. If you have content that's wider than this (e.g. your image) it'll zoom out even further. Seeing as how your `window.innerWidth` is 1248, that implies a scale factor of about 30%.

tl;dr: `innerWidth/innerHeight` reflect viewport with the pinch-zoom factor applied and the page is loaded fully zoomed out.

EDIT: This has since changed in Chrome. `window.innerWidth` now returns the *layout viewport* width. To get the visual viewport width, use `window.visualViewport.width`. See [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/visual-viewport-api) for more details.

Comment: GREAT explanation. Thank you. I tried to upvote your question, but I need at least 15 rep :(

Comment: I had an issue using Device Toolbar where ``window.innerHeight`` was I thought wrong. It turned out it was because I was using ``<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`` changing ``initial-scale=1`` to ``minimum-scale=1`` resolved this.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if this is a recent update (since the last responses), but I was able to find the viewport height/width by using:

```
window.screen.width
```

and

```
window.screen.height
```

This was particularly useful when I was trying to test whether the screen was phone-sized or not.

Comment: Holy crap, compatible with IE 4: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen

Comment: This doesn't work on iPhone.

Answer (score 6):

We're currently having success with something like:

```
    const widths = [window.innerWidth];

    if (window.screen?.width) {
      widths.push(window.screen?.width);
    }

    const width = Math.min(...widths);
```

The conditional check is there because I'm not sure how widespread the screen width API is. You may need to adjust this not to use certain newer JS features depending on what devices you are targeting/your build process.

This could potentially go a bit weird if you have a window that is wider than the screen, but for us that isn't a problem.

This gives us a width that matches the one at the top of the Responsive screen tool, even when contents overflow horizontally. This is important for us because we needed the UI to change in order to prevent that overflow, but the overflow was interfering with the width number we used to trigger the adjustment.

I'm not sure if this is important, but we are also using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```