# In Chrome devTool, why the console.log(window.innerWidth)=981, while it is set as iphone6 mode(375*667)

Tags: html, css

Please refer the image for detail:[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved when I add a meta in head:

Can refer here:
https://www.cnblogs.com/2050/p/3877280.html

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no,target-densitydpi=high-dpi,initial-scale=1.0,minimun-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" />

Comment: This answer may helps, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36317697/2469567