# Media queries getting applied at wrong width

Tags: css

I have a very simple media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .tool-panel {
        margin: 0px 24px 0px 0px;
    }
}
```

which gets applied at `1183.20px` instead of `1200px`. This is occurring in every browser and all browsers have their zoom levels set to 100%.

Also, this non-integer width looks weird as I have always dealt with integral values before while debugging on a browser.

[image]

However, when I check the value of `window.innerWidth` in the console, it comes out to be `1200` when the browser shows the width to be `1183.20px`.

Comment: can you try zooming out to 90% and then back to 100%? I had this issue once and that fixed it.

Comment: Tried that but I'm having the same results. I tried it with different browsers too.

Comment: How do you check that is width 1183.20px can you provide screenshot

Comment: is your code on a local or live server? if live then provide a link

Comment: @Aman localhost

Comment: Is there a vertical scrollbar? c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339377/how-to-get-screen-width-without-minus-scrollbar/8340177

Comment: It certainly must be the scrollbar. However, I'm stumped at the float value of width. How do we get that?

Comment: @schmauch Yes, that's what I wrote in a comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> which gets applied at 1183.20px instead of 1200px. This is occurring in every browser and all browsers have their zoom levels set to 100%.

`max-width: 1200px` is apply for range `0 to 1200px`. So if you want the inside css is just apply for `1200px` and not apply for `1183.20px`, you should use `min-width: 1200px`

```
//                      ↓↓↓
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .tool-panel {
        margin: 0px 24px 0px 0px;
    }
}
```

Try to check the below `meta` tag in your HTML, if it doesn't exists, add it in and try again.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

> However, when I check the value of window.innerWidth in the console,
> it comes out to be 1200 when the browser shows the width to be
> 1183.20px.

The answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36317697/5436211

Comment: Won't `min-width: 1200px` just correspond to the range `1200px to infinity`? Also, with `min-width`, I am experiencing the same behavior, that is the query takes effect at widths `1183.20px` and greater.

Comment: @KobayakiTunnel `max-width: 1200px` is still apply for `1183.20px` `1000px` `900px` `600px` until have another break point like `max-width: 992px`. That's right, nothing is wrong here.

Comment: @KobayakiTunnel updated more detail in the answer.

Comment: I am using that `meta` tag already. Also, I have found the solution to my issue which had to do with the width of the scrollbar. Anyways, thanks for your input and time.